# C# Visual Studio Web Browser Script Error

Tags: c#, web, browser

So I've updated my web browser via emulation in the registry so it's using the most updated version of IE, yet I still get this script error. I looked at the actual script and it does have some weird looking stuff with lots of random symbols so let me know if you know how I can fix this. I would recommend going to the link to look at the js [Click Here](https://d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/assets/pooky.min-d422b7a3637a3f3cbee9a32be42a1ac3.js) (**This is the web browser windows form component, not the normal IE browser!**)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Allow Scripts in IE

```
Select the "Tools" menu. ...
Select "Internet Options" ...
Select the "Security" tab. ...
Click the "Custom Level..." ...
Scroll down and change the Active Scripting setting. ...
Confirm the change. ...
Close "Internet Options" ...
JavaScript is now enabled.

[![see below image][1]][1]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYj1w.jpg
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I am using visual studio and the Web Browser component, not internet explorer.

Comment: try to explain more your Question , it look like so

Comment: Basically I am using the web browser component in visual studio on my windows form and I updated the internal browser to the latest version of IE yet when I go to the designated web page and it tries using that script it causes an error for some reason.